# extra row appearing in generated excel

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm using npm package [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx) to generate excel reports which have table within table. everything is working fine except you can see in the attached screenshot that line#10 is the same as all the table below that. I'm sure i'm making an html table error but after two hours could not figure out what the error actually is. I've attached the screenshot and html.

[image: Screenshot of report]

```
import React from 'react';

const Report = ({ data }) => {
  // console.log(data);
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style={{ width: '200px', backgroundColor: 'yellow' }}>
            Source Name:
          </td>
          <td>SOme cool report</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Report Name:</td>
          <td colSpan='6'>
            02 Dummy
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr />
        <tr>
          <td>Data Write:</td>
          <td>Append to Previous Data</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Download Date:</td>
          <td>19/04/2021 13:16</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SR Id:</td>
          <td>99931</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Data Period:</td>
          <td> 2021/3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Report Period: </td>
          <td>Monthly </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>sdfasdfasdf:</td>
          <td>sdfsdf</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td></td>
                  <td colSpan='2'>Less than 1</td>
                  <td colSpan='2'>{'1-4'}</td>
                  <td colSpan='2'>{'5-9'}</td>
                  <td colSpan='2'>{'10-14'}</td>
                  <td colSpan='2'>{'15-19'}</td>
                  <td colSpan='2'>{'20-24'}</td>
                  <td colSpan='2'>{'25-44'}</td>
                  <td colSpan='2'>{'45-64'}</td>
                  <td colSpan='2'>{'65+'}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>Dummy</td>
                  <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
                  <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
                  <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
                  <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
                  <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
                  <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
                  <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
                  <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
                  <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
                </tr>
                {Object.keys(data).map((d) => (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{d}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.abc?.male}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.abc?.female}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.cde1?.male}</td>{' '}
                    <td>{data[d]?.cde1?.female}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.cde2?.male}</td>{' '}
                    <td>{data[d]?.cde2?.female}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.cde3?.male}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.cde3?.female}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.abcd1?.male}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.abcd1?.female}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.abcd2?.male}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.abcd2?.female}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.ere1?.male}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.ere1?.female}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.ere2?.male}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.ere2?.female}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.ou?.male}</td>
                    <td>{data[d]?.ou?.female}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

export default Report;
```

Comment: I'm wondering, is the nested table automatically generating a header row? Have you tried implementing without the extra table? I'm not sure how it's inclusion is beneficial to what you are trying to achieve as there is no separation in the actual xml itself.

Comment: There is a skip header property you can explore when calling the library method to convert your data

Comment: Can you provide object data? It would be easier to simulate the error.

Comment: @MeeraDatey you can populate any json object to iterate because issue is not due to data. I'm doing something wrong with html

Comment: This line can be potential problem -                    <td>{d}</td> but can't say without knowing {d}

Answer (score 5):

The nested table HTML structure is causing entire table to create extra row.

Delete this lines from your code - and that should remove extra line being added to excel sheet.

```
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
```

from your code.

See the corrected code here (You can not run it on codesandbox due to unsupported methods - but the code work on local setup)

https://codesandbox.io/s/extrarowexcelsheet-333cv?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import XLSX from "xlsx";
import { useRef } from "react";


const Report = () => {
  // Data is just placeholder
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([["Hello"], ["Bye"]]);
  const myContainer = useRef(null);

  const exportFile = () => {
  
    const ws = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(myContainer.current);
    const wb = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "SheetJS");
    /* generate XLSX file and send to client */
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, "sheetjs.xlsx");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2> This is Demo for StackOverFlow Issue #68269850</h2>
      <p> Extra row appearing in generated excel </p>
      <button
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#4CAF50", padding: "10px" }}
        onClick={exportFile}
      >
        Press Me to Generate Excel Sheet{" "}
      </button>

      <hr />

      <table ref={myContainer}>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td style={{ width: "200px", backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
              Source Name:
            </td>
            <td>SOme cool report</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Report Name:</td>
            <td colSpan="6">02 Dummy</td>
          </tr>
          <tr />
          <tr>
            <td>Data Write:</td>
            <td>Append to Previous Data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Download Date:</td>
            <td>19/04/2021 13:16</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>SR Id:</td>
            <td>99931</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data Period:</td>
            <td> 2021/3</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Report Period: </td>
            <td>Monthly </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>sdfasdfasdf:</td>
            <td>sdfsdf</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td colSpan="2">Less than 1</td>
            <td colSpan="2">{"1-4"}</td>
            <td colSpan="2">{"5-9"}</td>
            <td colSpan="2">{"10-14"}</td>
            <td colSpan="2">{"15-19"}</td>
            <td colSpan="2">{"20-24"}</td>
            <td colSpan="2">{"25-44"}</td>
            <td colSpan="2">{"45-64"}</td>
            <td colSpan="2">{"65+"}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Dummy</td>
            <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
            <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
            <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
            <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
            <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
            <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
            <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
            <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
            <td>Male</td> <td>Female</td>
          </tr>
          {Object.keys(data).map((d) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{d}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.abc?.male}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.abc?.female}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.cde1?.male}</td> <td>{data[d]?.cde1?.female}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.cde2?.male}</td> <td>{data[d]?.cde2?.female}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.cde3?.male}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.cde3?.female}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.abcd1?.male}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.abcd1?.female}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.abcd2?.male}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.abcd2?.female}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.ere1?.male}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.ere1?.female}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.ere2?.male}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.ere2?.female}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.ou?.male}</td>
              <td>{data[d]?.ou?.female}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Report;
```

Comment: @ImranNaqvi - did this solve your problem?  If so, please accept the answer and give the bounty to Meera :)